# jQuery bottom position or transition reverse?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem I can't find the solution to.

I have 4 Icons in a div like so:

```
<div class="icons">
     <img id="planung" src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/planung.png" />
     <img id="machbarkeit" src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/machbarkeit.png" />
     <img src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/entwicklung.png" />
     <img src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/innovation.png" />
</div>
```

Now I have text boxes above, which have a height and width of 0 like so:

```
<div class="ablauftext" id="planungtext">
        ASD
</div>
<div class="ablauftext" id="machbarkeittext">
        ASD
</div>
```

The text boxes are animated over the icons. For example "planungtext" is aligned on the top left of the icon "planung". The icons div has a width of 80% and the icons themself are positioned via justify. So now I'm using jQuery to get the position of every icon. Now the problem is, that offset only gets the top and left positions. Now when I set these positions and add the negative margin of the height, it is perfectly positioned on top of the icon. The problem is now, that the transition when I click my icon "planung" is from top left to bottom right. Ofcourse it is, as I set a top value.

Now two things which could make this work:

A) Is there some way to get the bottom position of my icon, rather than the top, 
or
B) Is there some way to reverse my transition?

Comment: Honestly, if it's an option, I would reformat your HTML to allow your icons to be in their own container, that way you can have your icon and your text inside a container that knows exactly where everything is much more easy than a positioned element

Comment: I don't really understand how you mean this. Could you give me a more specific example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example which might not necessarily be the answer is this:  Reformat your HTML so your icon and text are in the same containing div

```
<div class="icons">
    <div class="icon">
        <img id="planung" src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/planung.png" />
        <div class="ablauftext" id="planungtext">
            ASD
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <img id="machbarkeit" src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/machbarkeit.png" />
        <div class="ablauftext" id="machbarkeittext">
            ASD
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/entwicklung.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="assets/images/charts/ablauf/innovation.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, instead of using jquery `.position()` to find the position, you can just cut that part out and show and hide the text div.  Just `position:absolute` your images and text inside of the `.icon` class.

Leave a comment if you need more info.  If you do need more info, I might need more info from you.

Comment: this might work. I will test it on monday and let u know! thank you

Comment: @frederikwitte, no problem. Let me know if you run into other troubles with this